# Delegates/Protocols between UIView & UIViewController not working

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to run some delegates/protocols between an UIView and an UIViewController. I've got some other delegates/protocols to run in this project, but there's one that I am super stumped on.

I've searched through Google and SO but haven't found a solution yet so I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

Here's a snippet of my UIView...

```
class SideMenuHomeView: UIView {

var expansionState: SideMenuExpansionState!
var mapController: MapController!

enum SideMenuExpansionState {
    case NotExpanded
    case Expanded
}

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let mapController = MapController()
    mapController.menuDelegate = self
    expansionState = .NotExpanded
}   

func handleSideMenuToggle() {
    if expansionState == .NotExpanded {
        animateInputView(targetPosition: self.frame.origin.x + 300) { (_) in
            self.expansionState = .Expanded
        }
    }
}

extension SideMenuHomeView: SideMenuHomeDelegate {
    func handleSideMenuHome() {
         handleSideMenuToggle()
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet of my UIViewController...

```
class MapController: UIViewController {

    var menuDelegate: SideMenuHomeDelegate!

    @objc func handleOpenMenu() {
        menuDelegate?.handleSideMenuHome()
    }
}
```

Here's my Protocol.swift...

```
protocol SideMenuHomeDelegate {
    func handleSideMenuHome()
}
```

Adding SideMenuHomeView to MapController

```
func configureSideMenuHomeView() {
    sideMenuHomeView = SideMenuHomeView()
    view.addSubview(sideMenuHomeView)
    sideMenuHomeView.anchorwithConstant(top: view.topAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, trailing: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingLeading: -(view.frame.width - 20), paddingTrailing: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for the UIView to shift 300 pixels on the X-axis to the right when I tap a button on the UIViewController.

When I connect my animate code block to a button on the UIView, it works, so it's not that. I've figured it out to be my delegate/protocol code, but can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Would anyone happen to know what's wrong with my current code? And is there a suggested/better way of communicating between a UIView and a UIViewController?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll make an edit to my original post and put it under my protocol code block. I've just made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue will be fixed if you set `delegate` while adding `SideMenuHomeView` as below,

```
func configureSideMenuHomeView() {
    sideMenuHomeView = SideMenuHomeView()
    view.addSubview(sideMenuHomeView)
    self.menuDelegate = sideMenuHomeView
    sideMenuHomeView.anchorwithConstant(top: view.topAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, trailing: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingLeading: -(view.frame.width - 20), paddingTrailing: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
}
```

---

But you are using wrong delegation here. When you have `instance` of `SideMenuHomeView` then you don't need its `delegate` reference explicitly as you already have all the methods on the `instance`. It's like two references to same object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however it's still not working unfortunately. I also deleted the two lines from your previous comment.

Comment: Can you check this method `handleOpenMenu` is getting called? And `self.menuDelegate` is not `nil`?

Comment: handleOpenMenu is being called, it prints out a statement. But how would I check if self.menuDelegate is nil or not?

Comment: `print(self.menuDelegate == nil)`

Comment: that print statement returns false

Comment: Kamran! nevermind it works! you're a genius, I actually forgot to uncomment something else, but your solution 100% helped me solve this problem.

Comment: Before you leave, could i ask for clarification on something? I am a little confused about your explanation about what I was doing wrong. Why didn't I need to set a delegate in my SideMenuHomeView UIView class?

Comment: As you have class variable `sideMenuHomeView` inside `MapController` so you can directly use that inside `handleOpenMenu` as `self.sideMenuHomeView.handleSideMenuHome()`

Comment: OH! That makes 100% sense, thank you Kamran! wish I could give you much more good karma